# VMWare Fusion cannot connect to the NAT connection on my Mac

Tags: nat, vmware-fusion

I have been using VMWare Fusion on my Mac to check out my websites on localhost.
Now I can't connect anymore with the NAT connection.
There seems to be a problem with my IP address or Mac address?

I have no idea what causes this, it was working fine before!?

In the XP (SP2) VM, in the taskbar I see the Local Area Connection with the yellow warning icon. The bubble says: 
"This connection has limited or no connectivity. You might not be aisle to access the Internet or some network resources. For more information, click this message."

Doing that opens up the Local Area Connection Status panel.
In the Support tab, when I click the repair button I get following message: "Windows could not finish repairing the problem because the following action cannot be completed: Renewing IP address."

I tried disabling my firewall and also XAMPP that I use as server on OSX.
VMWware version: 3.1
VM: XP SP2
Mac OSX 10.6.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

from: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/580365

```
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start
```

Comment: This worked for me on VMware Fusion 11.5.6 on macOS Catalina. Thanks! The other answer with `boot.sh` is not relevant to newer VMware releases.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying two things, first:
/Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Fusion/boot.sh  --restart
this restarts the dhcp server serving the NAT network
if that fails, try powering down the VM, removing the NIC, booting, powering down, adding it again, booting.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I got it working again just with a simple reboot of my computer, thanks for reminding me, I always just put her into sleep.
Now if I could just get localhost to work. Do you happen to now this? Is special configuration required? I remember from my other computer there was something like adding a network adapter... 
I am using Xampp.

Comment: well I think you're asking how to view sites runnining on your mac from your VM. Verify your Mac's IP address on the NAT LAN and try to reach that to view your sites.